# Why my android application hangs for the first time whenever i install it freshly?

Tags: android, xml, database

Whenever I install my **android application** it **jams** up my phone to create my **xml database** of almost 5K elements after its created it, it runs very smoothly.... 
This makes my users feel that my application is full of crap stuffs so they generally tend to dislike my android application.

---

Please help me out as I know that there must be a solution to my problem as there are many apps that have very large database even larger than mine but they dont hang for the f

Comment: show your code for other to optimize it if possible

Comment: Is this database device dependant? If not why are you creating it on the fly instead of shipping it with your app? Create it once and save it into your project

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: sorry for that but I got my problems solved as Vinil and Anirudh have helped me out very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to insert all those records in background using async task, refer this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Async task consists of two main sections doinbackground and onpostexecute, in doinbackground we can make all the UI independent mechanism like data base operations, executing httprequest. In postexecute we can do UI operations

Comment: While true, more information would make this a better answer. As is, it's more of a comment

Comment: Thanks a lot Vinil ... ur help was a such a relief to me ... :)

Answer (score 0):

your application hangs because you are performing your database creation on main thread so its blocks the ui.You can follow the approach as mentioned by VINIL SATRASALA or alternatively what you can do is to create all the database it a splash screen when the app runs for the first time.Splash is used for loading extra data,so use it properly.Also place a check on your splash screen to avoid creation of tables everytime the app is started.The easy way is to check whether there are records in table if yes then bypasss the table creation and if no then create and enter data.
here is an example-

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Splash_Activity.this,Main_Screen_activity.class);

                    DB_Handler_food db1 = new DB_Handler_food(Splash_Activity.this);// db1 is object of database handler class


                    if(db1.getRecordCount()==0){   //get record count checks no. of records
                        //adding data in database food
                        Log.v("reching", "table 1");
                        db1.addData(new Table_items("Eggs",Const_String_Food.egg_benefits , Const_String_Food.egg_positives,"eggs" ));
                        db1.addData(new Table_items("Brown Rice",Const_String_Food.brown_rice_benefits,Const_String_Food.brown_rice_positives,"brown_rice"));
                        db1.addData(new Table_items("Black Beans",Const_String_Food.black_beans_benefits,Const_String_Food.black_beans_positives,"black_beans"));

                    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Anirudh ... ur help was a such a relief to me ... :)

Comment: @AdityaPrasun if it helped you then please accept my answer by clicking the tick mark:)